# Charting library for Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile

Tags: charts, skiasharp, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

In a previous Xamarin native application, I used Microcharts, which is a charting library for .net. Using Microcharts, we had the chart-related logic in the shared part (we used MVVM) and just used charting components on each platform. I was wondering if there is any equivalent for Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile? I'd like to have the charting logic in the shared part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there isn't one that you're looking for.

You could still share your charting logic in KMM, exposing all the chart related information to the platform specific Views, then map that data if needed for the specific library you'd use on iOS/Android.

I think it's best if you don't mix view related libraries, since this way you still get the flexibility of choosing any chart library for any platform